# Push firebase project to open github repo?

Tags: android, firebase, github, firebase-realtime-database

I want to push a firebase project to an open source github repo. However, I want to secure it, I want to hide the path to database so that no one can read or write to it.

Is there a certain file in my project I shouldn't include in the repo?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid including the `google-services.json` file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to conceal the details of your project, don't check in google-services.json, which is the general advice for open source Android projects that use Firebase.

If you publish a version of your app to the Play store, it can be decompiled, and the contents of your google-services.json effectively become public.  So, if you are concerned about security, you should mostly pay attention to your app's security rules to make sure that random people cannot read and write data that they shouldn't.